# Using wave file resource with MediaPlayer

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin and Android Studio by following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/C_Ka7cKwXW0) in Java that creates a `MediaPlayer` and plays a wave file. I am trying to adapt the code to Kotlin:

**`MainActivity.kt`**:

```
package com.example.debugwaveres

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.view.View

//class MainActivity(private val context: Context) : AppCompatActivity() {
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var player: MediaPlayer? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun play(view: View) {
        if (player == null) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.metro1)
            player?.setOnCompletionListener {
                //stopPlayer()
            }
        }
        player?.start()
    }
}
```

The `.wav` resource `R.raw.metro1` has been copied to the `res/raw` resource directory:

---

[image]

---

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="play"
        android:text="Play" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This compiles fine in Android Studio using an AVD with target Android 9.0, but when I click the play button I get an Exception `java.io.IOException: Prepare failed` :

```
04/07 19:36:36: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 28.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.debugwaveres/com.example.debugwaveres.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 11210 on device 'Pixel_2_API_28 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1282)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:983)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:954)
        at com.example.debugwaveres.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code. It works fine. But you can try like this:

```
fun play(view : View) {
    if (player == null) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.metro1)
        player?.setOnCompletionListener {
            //stopPlayer()
        }
    }
    player?.setOnPreparedListener {
        it.start()
    }
}
```